# Is the certificate thumbprint guaranteed to be lowercase

Tags: security, certificate

I have a data store with the thumbprint values for all the certificates used by the system I am working on. Going through the data store (which has thousands of entries), I see that all the thumbprint values are lowercase. I tried searching online to ascertain if the thumbprint is guaranteed to be lowercase but couldn't find a definitive answer for it.

The reason I care about this is because the queries used for fetching data from the data store are currently trying to convert all values to lowercase before comparing to the incoming value, which is causing perf issues. I am trying to determine if the case conversion can be removed.

Can someone confirm whether the thumbprint is always going to be lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the thumbprint is a number (ok, **actually** is a bunch of bytes that can be interpretated as a number), and what you see in lowercase is the hexadecimal representation of that number.

Example (with a small number), consider this single byte:

- 00001111 (in binary)

In decimal, that's number 15, and in hexadecimal is 0f. So I could write it as the string `0f` or `0F`. It doesn't matter if it's lower or upper case, because it represents the same value (the same byte). Basically that's how thumbprint is displayed.

So it's not guaranteed that will always be lower case, because it depends on the tool you're using.

Answer (score 0):

thumbprint is a computed field. It is a hash of the certificate binary data. The hash can be computed with different algorithms such as MD5, SHA1 or SHA256.

It is not important if the thumbprint is represented in lowercase or uppercase. It depends on the software that shows the result. But take into account that the content will be different if you apply a different hash algorithm.